Getting 401 error while stoping mongodb cluster hosted in mongo atlas inspite giving correct public and private keys
TASK [mongodb : Stop MongoDB Atlas Cluster] ************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "connection": "close", "content_length": "0", "date": "Tue, 30 Jul 2024 17:50:54 GMT", "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was 401 and not [200]: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized", "redirected": false, "server": "mdbws", "status": 401, "url": "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/5d47c17b0360f591d40da2b/clusters/tst-eep-db-team", "www_authenticate": "Digest realm="MMS Public API", domain="", nonce="LVCLRABnfPG6LAXEH7pQYNpJvvJNRxYO", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth", stale=false", "x_envoy_upstream_service_time": "8"}
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

name: Stop MongoDB Atlas Cluster
uri:
url: "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/{{ project_id }}/clusters/{{ cluster_name }}"
method: PUT
user: "{{ mongodb_atlas_public_key }}"
password: "{{ mongodb_atlas_private_key }}"
force_basic_auth: yes
headers:
Content-Type: "application/json"
Accept: "application/json"
body_format: json
body: >
{
"paused": true
}
register: result

I want know why is it giving 401 error.
